# Where should we handle the cache fail-over on logic

Tags: php, failover, symfony-2.7, cache-failover

I developed a `PHP` application with `Symfony-2` and I need to handle `cache` fail-over on my application layer. As an illustrate, imagine you have to take care of performance and you're forced to generate an accurate response in your application. Also, you couldn't have clustered `cache` for `high-availability` in your application, so you need to check if the `cache` connection broke, then you should switch to `DB` handler and for the first time that you able to consume from the `cache`, you have to update your cache from the `DB`.

I'm wondering how could I `invalidate` my cache and where should I put this logic in my business.

Comment: A decorator pattern should do the trick, over your services. But the approach depends on the app structure...

Comment: thanks, @ka_lin, but how could I handle data cache validity? Imagine we lose connection with `Redis`  for 20secs and in this time some changes happen in data, after this scenario `Redis` data is not valid anymore, how could I handle it in `decorator` pattern?

Comment: If cache is invalid or you loose connection then you would query the data and save it to cache (if possible and it might be available on next call, else nothing happens and the next request will be a db call). You could use event handlers when data is changed and you could invalidate cache. The tricky part is making the cache keys and figure out namespaces imo